# mobile web app - keyboard not appearing

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile, web, mobile-website

I have a mobile web application, working well on simulator 5.1/6.0, xcode 4.5 for iphone.
But when I test on a real device (3gs, ios 5.1), I get a strange behavior: anywhere I place an input field html element, where I need the user to fill in something, I tap the field, it gains focus (I see the cursor), but the touch-keyboard does not come up and I can't type anything. If I try it on the sim, all is fine, the kb comes up.

I am not sure how to diagnose this... tried googling for some answers, haven't found any :(

any ideas?

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the issue, seems like the app was not created using the latest Xcode template (it is a legacy app), so I removed the MainWindowxxx.xibs which I don't need, and used the code from a new XCode app template to initialize the app by programmatically creating the main view controller, and setting it as the window's rootViewController. And, of course, call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]